# Wrong atoi() output in some parts of an array

Tags: c, atoi, strtol

I'm reading an input file and writing it to a 2D integer array. All the numbers in the file have two characters.

It works good but in all the [48]–[57] elements the integers have a redundant digit (e.g., 30, 871, 447 instead of 3, 87, 44). The same problem with strtol(). The hexadecimal codes of the input file look absolutely normal in those parts.

```
for (int a = 0; a < d; a++)
{
    for (int b = 0; b < d; b++)
    {
        //read two chars
        uint16_t num;
        fread(&num, sizeof(char) * 2, 1, inptr);

        //convert to int and put to the array (it makes wrong int in 48 <= b <= 57)
        arr[a][b] = atoi((char*)&num);

        //skip space or line break in the input file
        fseek(inptr, sizeof(char), SEEK_CUR);
    }
}
```

What's the problem? Why do only [48]–[57] work incorrectly?

Comment: You should provide a [mre]. In this case you should create a simple main function and remove `fread` and just load `num` with a number that does not work. If you cannot find such a number then you can probably create a [mre] without `atoi` instead.

Comment: And besides, `sizeof(char)` is just a fancy way of writing `1` ;)

Comment: Also, what is your file encoding? Seem l it seems that you are expecting every number to be separated by**exactly** one character, which might not be the case, especially for new lines

Comment: For data such as you describe, your program exhibits undefined behavior as a result of `atoi()` performing an out-of-bounds access, as a result, in turn, of the data you are feeding to it not being null-terminated within the bounds of `num`.  Technically, "undefined" means that there's no need to explain why misbehavior occurs for some input data and not for other data, but in practice, I suspect that fixing that problem will not resolve the observed misbehavior.

Comment: I would give it about 90% certainty that the issue is in the input, not the program, UB notwithstanding.

Comment: `atoi` requires a null terminator, but your `fread` does not add a null terminator. It just reads two characters from the file, neither of which is likely to be `\0`. (It's also not clear why you are type-punning into a `uint16_t`. Why not read into an array of characters?)

Comment: File is .txt, spaces and new lines are always 1 char, I checked the hexadecimal code of the file. I'll try to change it with and array of characters once again, but last time I had some errors I tried to avoid.

Comment: You *might* be able to get away with something like `char tmp[3]; fread(tmp, 2, 1, inptr); tmp[2] = '\0'; arr[a][b] = atoi(tmp);`.  But it looks like `fread` is probably the wrong tool for the job.  And `atoi((char*)&num)` is just wrong on the face of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments, especially for those mentioning the `\0` required for `atoi`.

Using `char str[3]` instead of `uint16_t` removes the problem and lets convert all the numbers correctly.

```
for (int a = 0; a < d; a++)
{
    for (int b = 0; b < d; b++)
    { 
        char str[3];
        str[2] = '\0';
        fread(&str, 2, 1, inptr);
        arr[a][b] = atoi(str);
        fseek(inptr, 1, SEEK_CUR);
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to `(char*)&num` NOT being a string, `atoi` provides zero error detection and zero way to validate the conversion -- so your invalid use of `atoi` in your original code could not be detected. This is why production code should always use `strtol` or `strtoul` and fully validate (1) that digits were converted, (2) the conversion did not set `errno` and if the resulting type is smaller than the size of the conversion (3) that the value is within range of the final type used.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin All very true, but kinda moot given that he's using `fseek(inptr, 1, SEEK_CUR)` to blindly skip over a character that might be a space, might be a newline, or might accidentally be another digit...

Comment: Agreed, example input would be very helpful in this case. Though the use of `atoi` versus `strtol`, etc.. would remain the same.